# Google Cloud Vision Request no image error

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, computer-vision, google-vision

I'm sure I'm missing something simple, but I can' get it to work:

```
const request = {
                    "requests": [
                      {
                        "image": {
                          "source": {
                            "imageUri":
                              `gs://${bucketName}/thumbnails/${fileName}`,
                          },
                        },
                      },
                    ],
                  };
const [textDetection] = await client.textDetection(request);
```

throws error: No image present. at _coerceRequest

However, with

```
const request = `gs://${bucketName}/thumbnails/${fileName}`
const [textDetection] = await client.textDetection(request);
```

everything works fine.
I already read the documentation (https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/vision/latest/v1.ImageAnnotatorClient.html#textDetection) and searched the web for hints, but it doesn't seem to be a problem for other users.

What am I missing, I'm going crazy over this one :(

Comment: By **rapidly** reading the doc I'm wondering why do you use a `requests` array?? As said in the doc, the `textDetection` method "annotates a **single** image with text detection."

Comment: In addition why don't you use the simplified syntax (```const request = `gs://${bucketName}/thumbnails/${fileName}```) since it works and is explicitly advised in the documentation ("For simple cases, you may also send a string (the URL or filename of the image) ")? There isn't any reason to not use it since you only pass an URL (unless you plan to use the `features` or `imageContext` properties).

Comment: As you mentioned, I want to use features and context for my future requests, as well as send blobs directly instead of URLs. I just wonder why it doesn‘t work.. in the doc it says: If the key is `source`, the value should be another object containing
`imageUri` or `filename` as a key and a string as a value.

Comment: Can you try with ```const request = {"image": {"source": {"imageUri": `gs://${bucketName}/thumbnails/${fileName}`}}}```?

Comment: tried it and it works, i thought I have tried this before but apparently not :) thanks buddy

Comment: Glad I could help you! I'll write an answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use an array of [`request`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/vision/latest/google.cloud.vision.v1.AnnotateImageRequest.html)s. As said in the documentation, the [`textDetection()`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/vision/latest/v1.ImageAnnotatorClient.html#textDetection) method "annotates a **single** image with text detection."

So defining the `request` Object as follows should do the trick.

```
  const request = {
    image: {
      source: { imageUri: `gs://${bucketName}/thumbnails/${fileName}` },
    },
  };
```